# Does concavity imply that $f'(a)<\frac {f(a)}a$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, economics

Does concavity imply that $f'(a)<\frac {f(a)}a$ ? I have read this in the proof of a paper by Straub, Mian and Sufi (https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/straub/files/mss_indebteddemand.pdf), appendix B.1. and I did not know this before. Does anybody know the proof of this or why this holds?

Comment: Can you state the result more clearly, so we understand what the restrictions are? In general, this is false (see for instance what happens with $f(x) = 1-x^2$)

Comment: I thought this was a general formulation, but this was because I missed a line up in the paper. Anonymous answered very effectively below. Thanks a lot for your input, though

Answer (score 0):

See equation (3) page 7, $\eta(a)=a\nu'(a)$. Thus if $\nu$ is concave, $\nu''<0$ so,
$$\eta'(a)=\nu'(a)+a\nu''(a)<\nu'(a)=\frac1a(a\nu'(a))=\frac{\eta(a)}{a}.$$

Comment: Magnificent. Thanks a lot